# Submitting Form using AJAX won't POST to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am basically trying to submit the form to the database, but it won't POST for some reason. There was a hit on the success method triggering success. So, I'm not sure what the problem is? I checked the database in phpMyAdmin to see if the data was submitted, but that didn't pan out either. I tried looking around to see similar code on this site and jquery's to find solutions but still failed. Any solutions?

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form" method="post">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/011.jpg" alt="011.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
      <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
      <input type="hidden"  name="price" value="64.99"/>
      <h4 title="Item">Second Product</h4>
      <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="product"/>
      <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="description" value="DESC VALUE"/>
    </div>
    <div class="userOptions text-center">
    <!-- Cart Button -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="cartButton" name="addItemToCart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add to Cart</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**JQuery/AJAX:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $(".form").on("submit",function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'cartexe.php', //I will put project id here as well
            data:$(".form input").serialize(),
            success:function(smsg)
            {
                alert('success added');
            }
        });


   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's in 'cartexe.php'?

Comment: inside cartexe.php is the code to post the information to the data. I use action="cartexe.php" to verify that the code is working and it post successfully. It only doesnt work when try to submit via ajax

Comment: what do you mean it wont post? where are the PHP codes?

Comment: Right, but from what we've seen so far there's no way to tell why it's not saving the db record

Comment: Any errors in the console ?

Comment: show the cartexe.php code

Comment: I can verify that. Like I said earlier, When I do <form action="cartexe.php"></form> instead of ajax the data shows up in the database and add new records. However when I try to implement ajax method submitting the request to cartexe without modifying it, the data is not showing up in the database at all.

Comment: Do you have Firefox?  Try using Firebug to see what the response is from cartexe.php.  I think Chrome and Internet Explorer each have their own developer view as well.

Comment: firebug shows that all is good. Anyway, here is the cartexe code http://pastebin.com/WUERvWZf and this is the function code that is stored in another file http://pastebin.com/Fxf6zfvB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add addItemToCart (`data:$(".form input").serialize()+"&addItemToCart="`) to your data for ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $(".form").on("submit",function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'cartexe.php', //I will put project id here as well
            data:$(".form input").serialize()+"&addItemToCart=",
            success:function(smsg)
            {
                alert('success added');
            }
        });


   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be this:

```
data:$(".form input").serialize(),
```

Since you explicitly `.form input`, `<input>` tags only, and then in your PHP, you are checking the existsnce of `if(isset($_POST['addItemToCart']))`, which is actually a `button` tag, which is **not included** and transported in the post data.

So basically, nothing happens, since you rely on that `<button>` tag.

So instead, convert the button into an input type submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="addItemToCart" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary" id="cartButton" />
```

Although it might conflict your styling.

I might also suggest, instead of trigger it from the setting of the button use this instead:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // PHP Logic
}
```

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight you could change the button, check my revision

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'` you really don't have to worry about that button at all, and you get to keep that button tag with styling

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight anyway, this would it looks like, http://codepad.viper-7.com/oO8RZ5, by the way, the accepted answer is much simpler. + 1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to post to cartext.php using your code. No errors in firebug and received an ok return message. Post data is present. What problem are you encountering?